# Capture filter of an excel cell/column and header and footer of excel sheet using win32::OLE in perl

Tags: excel, perl, win32ole

1. How to capture a filter defined for a particular cell of a column in a Microsoft excel sheet using Win32::OLE. Is there any inbuilt function for checking if a filter is defined for that cell and then for capturing?
2. How to capture the header and footer of the excel sheet using Win32:OLE?

Have been searching a lot but could not find anything.